# How to copy a Postgresql varchar column to an integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table named `baseballs` with a column named `quantity` of type = varchar and would like to populate the `quantity_integer` column with type = integer

How would I write a SQL statement?

Answer (score 9):

```
update baseballs set quantity_integer = quantity::int;
```

Comment: Correct.  In any strongly typed language you have to cast from one type to another.  Because of asymetric conversions automatic casting means the db would have to guess whether it's better to cast  text to int or an int to text.  Also there's also the ANSI SQL cast(field to type) you can use but I prefer the :: casting operator.  it's obvious and easy to remember.

Comment: @richardd capitalizing keywords for "better readability" is a matter of opinion. I detest it, and countless psychological studies have shown that all caps is *less* readable than lowercase